# iOS 12 "Welcome to Apple Music" keeps coming

Tags: iphone, apple-music, music.app

I just want to listen to *my own music* on iPhone.

I just want to open Music where it was the last time.

I don't want to join "Apple music". Not now. Not ever.

I don't want to say "Not now" *each time* Apple ask me to join Apple Music.

So I cut the cellular access to Music, even signed out of "Home sharing", but still, that thing comes again.

Seriously, how to get rid of that annoying advertisement, for good?

Comment: Yeah, this would drive me to a sad place. I’ve suggested an alternate player since even when subscribed to Apple Music, the apple app does things I don’t like - I can’t manage bandwidth when roaming, shuffle only songs I have cached locally, etc... https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cs-music-player/id924491991?mt=8

Comment: Did it (Cs Music), and feel already satisfied after 5 minutes use! Thanks. By the way, that fixed also [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359082/iphone-music-search-in-my-library-doesnt-find-words-in-titles) about Music search not working correctly (Apple, where are you going??).

Comment: Please edit my answer if you can make it more clear as to use cases - it's an amazing app and I find myself paying over and over for things that delight me on iOS - paid apps FTW for a refined UI / powerful or something Apple just can't or won't do.